# Ajax form only working after first refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I've a form that is sent via AJAX, but AJAX only works after first refresh (F5).

The first time I open the html I send the form and I've to do a page refresh otherwise data it is not submited. After this first refresh, AJAX is working perfectly and always reflect new data on success.

The data that I append after submits the form: ( $("#fldIdLetraN") and $("#fldLetraN") ), I've to call it via $_REQUEST on php file, I think this can do some interference the first time form is sent because data isn't really insert in JSON file cause $_REQUEST is not setting correctly.

```
    $("body").on("submit", "#frmPersonas", function(e) {
    $("#fldIdLetraN").val(jQuery.inArray(RemoveAccents($("#fldNombre").val().substr(0, 1)), $aLetras));
    $("#fldLetraN").val(RemoveAccents($("#fldNombre").val().substr(0, 1)));
    var fd = new FormData($("#frmPersonas")[0]);
    $.ajax({type: 'POST',
        url: "procjson.php",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function() {
            CargarPagina($LetraAct, $IdLetraAct, $PagActual);
            $("#form").css("display", "none");
            $("#formbg").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The entire code:

```
        <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Agenda</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="formbg">
            <div id="form"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="divAgenda">
            <div id="divLetras"></div>
            <div id="divEditar">
                <a href="#add" id="add"><div><img src="img/ops/add.png" alt="" /></div></a>
                <a href="#update" id="update"><div><img src="img/ops/update.png" alt="" /></div></a>
                <a href="#delete" id="delete"><div><img src="img/ops/delete.png" alt="" /></div></a>
            </div>
            <div id="divBusqueda">
                <a href="#hojear" id="hojear"><div><img src="img/ops/hojear.png" alt="" /></div></a>
                <a href="#search" id="search"><div><img src="img/ops/search.png" alt="" /></div></a>
            </div>
            <div id="divPersonas"></div>
            <div id="divPaginas"></div>
            <div id="divDesplazar">
                <a href="#first" id="first"><div><img src="img/move/first.png" alt="" /></div></a>
                <a href="#previous" id="prev"><div><img src="img/move/previous.png" alt="" /></div></a>
                <a href="#next" id="next"><div><img src="img/move/next.png" alt="" /></div></a>
                <a href="#last" id="last"><div><img src="img/move/last.png" alt="" /></div></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $aLetras = new Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j",
                "k", "l", "m", "n", "ñ", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v",
                "w", "x", "y", "z");
        for (var i = 0; i < $aLetras.length; i++) {
            $("#divLetras").append("<a href='#" + $aLetras[i] + "' id='" + $aLetras[i] + "-" + i + "'\n\
                                    class='tab-letra'>" + $aLetras[i].toUpperCase() + "</a>");
        }
        $PagActual = 0;
        CargarPagina("a", 0, 0);
    });
    function CargarPagina(letra, id_letra, pag_actual, hojear) {
        $.getJSON("datos.json", function(datos) {
            $("#divPersonas").empty();
            $("#divPersonas").append("<ul id='col1'></ul><ul id='col2'></ul>");
            var res_pagina = 6;
            for (var i = pag_actual * res_pagina; i < pag_actual * res_pagina + res_pagina; i++) {
                if (datos.personas[id_letra][letra][i] === undefined) {
                    break;
                }
                var html = "<div id='per" + datos.personas[id_letra][letra][i].id + "'>";
                html += "<div><img src='img/photo/" + datos.personas[id_letra][letra][i].foto + "' /></div>";
                html += "<div><span>Nombre: </span><span id='nom" + datos.personas[id_letra][letra][i].id + "'>";
                html += datos.personas[id_letra][letra][i].nombre + "</span><br />";
                html += "<span>Apellidos: </span><span id='ape" + datos.personas[id_letra][letra][i].id + "'>";
                html += datos.personas[id_letra][letra][i].apellidos + "</span><br />";
                html += "<span>Edad: </span><span id='eda" + datos.personas[id_letra][letra][i].id + "'>";
                html += datos.personas[id_letra][letra][i].edad + "</span><br />";
                html += "<span>Teléfono: </span><span id='tel" + datos.personas[id_letra][letra][i].id + "'>";
                html += datos.personas[id_letra][letra][i].telefono + "</span><br /></div></div>";
                if (i >= pag_actual * res_pagina && i < pag_actual * res_pagina + res_pagina - 3) {
                    $("#col1").append(html);
                } else {
                    $("#col2").append(html);
                }
            }
            $LetraAct = letra;
            $IdLetraAct = id_letra;
            if (datos.personas[id_letra][letra].length % res_pagina === 0) {
                $TotalPag = datos.personas[id_letra][letra].length / res_pagina - 1;
            } else {
                $TotalPag = Math.floor(datos.personas[id_letra][letra].length / res_pagina);
            }
            $("#divPaginas").empty();
            for (var i = 0; i <= $TotalPag; i++) {
                $("#divPaginas").append("<a href='#" + $LetraAct + ",p" + (i + 1) + "' id='pag" + i + "'>" + (i + 1) + "</a>");
            }
            if($TotalPag === -1) {
                $("#divPersonas").html("<div id='noRes'>No se ha encontrado ningún resultado.</div>");
            }
            if (hojear) {
                Hojear(true);
            }
        });
    }
    function GreyBox() {
        $("#form").fadeIn("fast", function() {
            $("#form").css("display", "block");
        });
        $("#formbg").fadeIn("fast", function() {
            $("#form").css("display", "block");
        });
    }
    function AbrirFormulario(crud, id_persona) {
        $("#form").html("<div id='frmOp'></div>\n\
                        <form id='frmPersonas' name='frmPersonas'>\n\
                        <label for='fldNombre'>Nombre:</label>\n\
                        <input type='text' id='fldNombre' name='fldNombre' autocomplete='off' />\n\
                        <label for='fldApellidos'>Apellidos:</label>\n\
                        <input type='text' id='fldApellidos' name='fldApellidos' autocomplete='off' />\n\
                        <label for='fldEdad'>Edad:</label>\n\
                        <input type='text' id='fldEdad' name='fldEdad' autocomplete='off' />\n\
                        <label for='fldTlf'>Teléfono:</label>\n\
                        <input type='text' id='fldTlf' name='fldTlf' autocomplete='off' />\n\
                        <input type='hidden' id='fldIdLetraN' name='fldIdLetraN' />\n\
                        <input type='hidden' id='fldLetraN' name='fldLetraN' />\n\
                        <input type='hidden' id='crud' name='crud' value='" + crud + "' />\n\
                        <input type='submit' id='btnEnviar' value='Enviar' /></form>\n\
                        <div id='frmAlert'></div>");
        if (crud === "C") {
            $("#frmOp").html("Agregar contacto");
        }
        if (crud === "U") {
            $("#frmOp").html("Modificar contacto");
            $("#fldNombre").val($("#nom" + id_persona).html());
            $("#frmPersonas").append("<input type='hidden' id='fldLetraAct' name='fldLetraAct' \n\
                                     value='" + RemoveAccents($("#fldNombre").val().substr(0, 1)) + "' />");
            $("#frmPersonas").append("<input type='hidden' id='fldIdLetraAct' name='fldIdLetraAct' \n\
                                     value='" + jQuery.inArray(RemoveAccents($("#fldNombre").val().substr(0, 1)), $aLetras) + "' />");
            $("#fldApellidos").val($("#ape" + id_persona).html());
            $("#fldEdad").val($("#eda" + id_persona).html());
            $("#fldTlf").val($("#tel" + id_persona).html());
            $("#frmPersonas").append("<input type='hidden' id='fldIdPersona' name='fldIdPersona' value='" + id_persona + "' />");
        }
    }
    function RemoveAccents(strAccents) {
        var strAccents = strAccents.split('');
        var strAccentsOut = new Array();
        var strAccentsLen = strAccents.length;
        var accents = 'ÁABCDÉEFGHÍIJKLMNÑÓOPQRSTÚUVWXYZ';
        var accentsOut = "aabcdeefghiijklmnñoopqrstuuvwxyz";
        for (var y = 0; y < strAccentsLen; y++) {
            if (accents.indexOf(strAccents[y]) !== -1) {
                strAccentsOut[y] = accentsOut.substr(accents.indexOf(strAccents[y]), 1);
            } else
                strAccentsOut[y] = strAccents[y];
        }
        strAccentsOut = strAccentsOut.join('');
        return strAccentsOut;
    }
    function Hojear(active) {
        if (active) {
            if ($TotalPag === -1) {
                $TotalPag = 0;
            }
            if ($PagActual === $TotalPag) {
                if ($IdLetraAct + 1 === $aLetras.length) {
                    $IdLetraAct = 0;
                    $LetraAct = $aLetras[$IdLetraAct];
                    $PagActual = 0;
                } else {
                    $IdLetraAct++;
                    $LetraAct = $aLetras[$IdLetraAct];
                    $PagActual = 0;
                }
            } else {
                $PagActual++;
            }
            $DelayHojear = setTimeout(function() {
                CargarPagina($LetraAct, $IdLetraAct, $PagActual, true);
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            clearTimeout($DelayHojear);
        }
    }
    $("body").on("click", "#divLetras a", function() {
        var letra = $(this).attr("id").substr(0, 1);
        var id_letra = $(this).attr("id").substr($(this).attr("id").search(/\d/));
        $PagActual = 0;
        CargarPagina(letra, id_letra, $PagActual);
    });
    $("#divDesplazar a").click(function() {
        var acc = $(this).attr("id");
        if (acc === "first") {
            $PagActual = 0;
        }
        if (acc === "prev" && $PagActual > 0) {
            $PagActual--;
        }
        if (acc === "next" && $PagActual < $TotalPag) {
            $PagActual++;
        }
        if (acc === "last") {
            $PagActual = $TotalPag;
        }
        CargarPagina($LetraAct, $IdLetraAct, $PagActual);
    });
    $("#divEditar a").click(function() {
        var acc = $(this).attr("id");
        if (acc === "update" || acc === "delete") {
            if ($("[id*=per]").hasClass("selected")) {
                var id_persona = $(".selected").attr("id").substr($(".selected").attr("id").search(/\d/));
                if (acc === "update") {
                    GreyBox();
                    AbrirFormulario("U", id_persona);
                }
                if (acc === "delete") {
                    var crud = "D";
                    $.ajax({type: "POST",
                        url: "procjson.php",
                        data: {'crud': crud, 'id_persona': id_persona, 'letra_act': $LetraAct, 'id_letra': $IdLetraAct},
                        success: function() {
                            CargarPagina($LetraAct, $IdLetraAct, $PagActual);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                console.log("no");
            }
        }
        if (acc === "add") {
            GreyBox();
            AbrirFormulario("C", -1);
        }
    });
    $("body").on("submit", "#frmPersonas", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#fldIdLetraN").val(jQuery.inArray(RemoveAccents($("#fldNombre").val().substr(0, 1)), $aLetras));
        $("#fldLetraN").val(RemoveAccents($("#fldNombre").val().substr(0, 1)));
        var fd = new FormData($("#frmPersonas")[0]);
        $.ajax({type: 'POST',
            url: "procjson.php",
            cache: false,
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function() {
                CargarPagina($LetraAct, $IdLetraAct, $PagActual);
                $("#form").css("display", "none");
                $("#formbg").css("display", "none");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    $("body").on("click", "#divPersonas [id*=p]", function() {
        $("#divPersonas [id*=per]").removeAttr("class");
        var id_persona = $(this).attr("id").substr($(this).attr("id").search(/\d/));
        $("#per" + id_persona).attr("class", "selected");
    });
    $("body").on("click", "#formbg", function() {
        $("#form").css("display", "none");
        $("#formbg").css("display", "none");
    });
    $("body").on("click", "#divPaginas a", function() {
        var id_pagina = $(this).attr("id").substr($(this).attr("id").search(/\d/));
        CargarPagina($LetraAct, $IdLetraAct, id_pagina);
    });
    $("#divBusqueda a").click(function() {
        var Acc = $(this).attr("id");
        if (Acc === "hojear") {
            Hojear(true);
        }
        if (Acc === "search") {

        }
    });
    $("body").on("mouseover", "[id*=per]", function() {
        Hojear(false);
    });
    $("#form").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        return false;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try disabling the cache:

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
    url: "procjson.php",
    cache: false
    //the rest
});
```

Comment: The problem was that getJSON was caching the file, so all AJAX requests, on success were calling the function that it shows the same data, so I put $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); on document ready and now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Is this all of your javascript code used on this site? Because if yes, try to wrap your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("submit", "#frmPersonas", function(e) {
        $("#fldIdLetraN").val(jQuery.inArray(RemoveAccents($("#fldNombre").val().substr(0, 1)), $aLetras));
        $("#fldLetraN").val(RemoveAccents($("#fldNombre").val().substr(0, 1)));
        var fd = new FormData($("#frmPersonas")[0]);
        $.ajax({type: 'POST',
            url: "procjson.php",
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function() {
                CargarPagina($LetraAct, $IdLetraAct, $PagActual);
                $("#form").css("display", "none");
                $("#formbg").css("display", "none");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Then jquery will wait before the DOM is ready before attaching the eventhandler etc., this could be an explanation why it's working on refresh (because of your browser cache dom could be ready faster then on your first load).

Comment: If I put js on document ready the form is send via GET and without AJAX, anyway, I use $("body").on("click"... and only append the form when his div is called, I think this solve what you say.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I get what you're saying, could you please provide the whole code of your page with this form and your js? $(document).ready() shouldn't affect your ajax request.

Comment: I've edited with the entire code, function AbrirFormulario() is the form, below is the jQuery event to call form.